# Twilio programmable custom voice call

Tags: sms, twilio, voip, voice, twilio-click-to-call

I've recently started to use Twilio, for our own needs - we need to provide users with real-time informations about possible dangerous events that might have happened at their home, through SMS or Voice call.

I've tried to use VoiceCall exactly as it's specificied here - https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/api-explorer/call-create. The scenario is that I want a robotic voice to explain what was happened, hence I need to generate the xml file for voice on demand. I supplied my own RestApi url for the voice, that is able to generate this file through TWIML.

By default Twilio, will use that url to fetch the audio and other instructions, at the moment when the call is performed. ***Since the voice URL cannot contain parameters (because they got cut off for some reason)*** (e.g **YES - http://mywebsite.com/api/sayVoice,  NO - http://mywebsite.com/api/sayVoice?eventId=1)**, you will ALWAYS get the same audio (no way to identify a different kind of event and generate a DIFFERENT xml output (for a different audio to the end user).

In Twilio documentation examples, they have only static URLs as well, without extra parameters, hence is that indeed the only way Twilio Call Api can be used?

It's hardly believable that such an use case was not planned for Twilio. 
Did anyone tried to use Twilio for a similar scenario?

**Any suggestions regarding similar technologies for the same purpose?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue in the end, you need to pass the parameters as RequestParams.

For example, this one will work - `Url=http://mywebsite.com/api/twilio/sayVoice?eventId=379`, while pathParam won't work `Url=http://mywebsite.com/api/twilio/sayVoice/379`.

Hence, stay safe and use RequestParams.